# URL parameters for Kibana 4 visualizations

Tags: kibana-4

I am trying to export the visualization from kibana using iframe export link. The link is as follows:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:5601/#/visualize/edit/line_chart_param_1-ampersand-2?embed&_a=(filters:!(),linked:!t,query:(query_string:(query:'*')),vis:(aggs:!((id:'1',params:(field:d.Universal_ID.n),schema:metric,type:sum),(id:'2',params:(field:d.CollectedOn.s,size:5),schema:segment,type:significant_terms)),listeners:(),params:(addLegend:!t,addTooltip:!t,defaultYExtents:!f,shareYAxis:!t),type:line))&_g=(time:(from:now-1d%2Fd,mode:quick,to:now-1d%2Fd))" height="600" width="800"></iframe>
```

I am using it as model for graph and varying the field. How much logical approach is it? Is there any documentation for url parameters used in kibana?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ?

Comment: Any solution/workaround to this yet?